# INTEL XDK FILETRANSFER ERROR

Tags: runtime-error, file-transfer, intel-xdk

I'm trying to download a file from internet and memorize on my mobile but I have a problem when define a variable type problem FileTransfer().
The message is:" FileTransfer is not defined".
I have put a cordova plugin filetransfer in a xml file.

Follow the code.
Thanks.

```
/* Intel native bridge is available */
var onDeviceReady=function()
{
//hide splash screen
intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();

try{
     var ft = new FileTransfer();
}catch(e)
{
  alert(e.message);
}
};
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about a cordova plugin like this one:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

In the Intel XDK you need to include all the cordova plugins that your project is using.  On the project page there's a collection of cordova plugins with check boxes for each one.  There are a few "core" plugins, like Accelerometer, Camera, File &c.  There are also "Featured and Custom" Plugins.

Below these are "Third Party Plugins".  Expand that and there's a button labeled "Get Plugin from the Web".  Click on that and enter the name ("FileTransfer"), the plugin id from the plugin.xml file ("org.apache.cordova.file-transfer") and the url of the git repository ("https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git").

Then click "Import" and you should be good to go.

Even though this is a plugin from Cordova, since it's not in the "Included Plugins" it's treated as a "Third party plugin".  Because of this, it will not be included in the Emulator, AppPreview or the Debug tab environment, so the only way to test it is to build the application and install the built app on a device.